Python Azure durable function performance issue
I have a python application which is running on the azure durable function. Implemented the application in the Fan out/fan in design patterns. But while submitting large number of parallel task to durable function it become slow. as far i my understanding the activity function are running on single instance.which making the resource to share for the activity function to run parallelly.
is there any configuration to run the activity function into sperate instance for each invocations of activity functions
python : 3.11
durable function  Fan out/fan in design patterns
looking for a Solution to run the activity functions into separate instance for each invocation of activity functions.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It might be cause of heavy load for this you need to use premium appservice plan instead of consumption plan,


while submitting large number of parallel task to durable function it become slow.

By default, activity functions within the same orchestrator instance can share the same process and runtime environment, potentially limiting parallelism and impacting performance, especially under heavy load.

By using a Premium App Service Plan for your Azure Functions, which provides more control over scaling and resources within this configure the number of instances to handle incoming requests, allowing for better parallelism of activity functions.
In function.json file of activity functions can be configure the batchSize and maxBatchSize settings to control how many activity function instances can execute in parallel. it can be adjust the workload requirement.
The below given sample batchsize in activity function of function.json file:

Function.json:
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "input",
      "type": "activityTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "batchSize": 100,
  "maxBatchSize": 100
}



As per the requirement manually can be change the batchSize for increase the scalability and performance.
By adjust WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT setting allows you to control the scalability and concurrency of function app.

